# Computing the inner product of vectors with allowed scalar values 0, 1 and 2 using AVX intrinsics

Tags: c++, simd, avx

I am doing inner product of two columns of dimension in tens of thousands. The values can only be 0, 1, or 2. They can be hence stored as characters. If to vectorize the calculation on a CPU with avx flag, I expect it to be ~32 times faster. But the problem is the multiplication automatically converts the characters to integers, which are 4 bytes. Thus a maximal of 8 times only in speed can be obtained. Can a speed of 32 times be reached?

btw, I am using Linux (Fedora 22 to date) with g++ 5.1.

Comment: The answer is yes. What was your question again? (You didn't even tell us which operating system or compiler you're using, which makes it *really* hard to be specific.)

Comment: I am using Linux, Fedora to be exact. the compiler is g++ 5.1. I also have a license of Intel C 2015. G++ is preferred.

Comment: AVX doesn't support `ymm` integer multiply.

Answer (score 13):

Assuming you have [AVX2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions#AVX2) (not just AVX, which is only really for floating point), then you can use the `vpmaddubsw` instruction, for which the intrinsic is:

```
__m256i _mm256_maddubs_epi16 (__m256i a, __m256i b)
```

This performs 8 bit x 8 bit multiply (signed x unsigned, but this doesn't matter for your case) and then adds pairs of adjacent terms to give a 16 bit result. [[1]](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/iss/2013/compiler/cpp-lin/GUID-60FFD6ED-DD75-4095-85B8-B53EC7D10F31.htm) This effectively gives you 32 x 8 x 8 bit bit multiplication in one instruction.

If you don't have AVX2 then you can use the 128 bit SSE version (`_mm_maddubs_epi16`) to get 16 x x 8 x 8 bit bit multiplication in one instruction.

Note that horizontally summing the 16 bit terms can take several instructions, but since your input range is quite small then you only need to perform this horizontal summation relatively infrequently. One possible method (for SSE):

```
v = _mm_madd_epi16(v, _mm_set1_epi16(1));       // unpack/sum 16 -> 32
v = _mm_add_epi32(v, _mm_srli_si128(v, 8));     // shift and add 32 bit terms
v = _mm_add_epi32(v, _mm_srli_si128(v, 4));
sum = _mm_cvtsi128_si32(v);                     // extract sum as scalar
```

An AVX2 implementation of the above is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Can you add the intrinsic for sideways 16-bit addition for completeness?

Comment: @KrzysztofKosiński: it's tough to do the horizontal add efficiently, but it only needs to be calculated fairly infrequently in this particular case. I'll add a note about that to the answer.

Answer (score 9):

It looks like the AVX instruction set does not have 8-bit multiplication, only addition. [The Intel intrinsics guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/) does not contain any 8-bit operations starting with `_mm_mul*`. (**edit**: in fact there is an 8-bit multiply, but it has a misleading name - see answer by @PaulR)

However, there is an alternate approach. Since the only allowed values are 0, 1 and 2, and you are computing an inner product, you can use bit operations instead of multiplications.

In the first vector `A`, use the following encoding:

```
0 = 0b00000000 = 0x00
1 = 0b00010011 = 0x13
2 = 0b00001111 = 0x0F
```

In the second vector `B`, use the following encoding:

```
0 = 0b00000000 = 0x00
1 = 0b00011100 = 0x1C
2 = 0b00001111 = 0x0F
```

Now compute `popcount(A & B)`. AND-ing will cause the respective 8-bit cells to have 0, 1, 2 or 4 bits set, and the `popcount` will add them together. You can pack one value per 5 bits of the integer, so if you can use 256-bit ints, you can get 51x higher throughput.

Comment: Wow, way out of the box, I'm impressed

Comment: See: `_mm_maddubs_epi16`/`_mm256_maddubs_epi16` (the `_epi16` suffix is somewhat misleading).

Comment: You can map a vector of 0s, 1s, and 2s, to this encoding by using it as the shuffle control mask for `VPSHUFB`.  (packing down to 5bits would be slower).  The vector to be shuffled only needs data in the low 3 bytes, so you can load it with a simple `VMOVD`.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that it is worth trying to do it via bit operations.

Suppose that all the numbers are either 0 or 1.
Then you can pack both vectors into bit arrays. The inner product is then computed by:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i += 256)
  res += popcount(A[i..i+255] & B[i..i+255]);
```

The *and* operation is naturally present in AVX/AVX2. The hardest question is how to compute popcount for YMM registers quickly.

Now suppose that we are given 0, 1, and 2. For each vector *A* of integers compose two bit-vectors *A1* and *A2*:

```
A1[i] = (A[i] >= 1);    
A2[i] = (A[i] >= 2);
```

Now we can notice that:

```
A[i] * B[i] = A1[i] * B1[i] + A1[i] * B2[i] + A2[i] * B1[i] + A2[i] * B2[i];
```

So we can compute inner product with the following pseudocode:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i += 256) {
  res += popcount(A1[i..i+255] & B1[i..i+255]);
  res += popcount(A2[i..i+255] & B1[i..i+255]);
  res += popcount(A1[i..i+255] & B2[i..i+255]);
  res += popcount(A2[i..i+255] & B2[i..i+255]);
}
```

This allows to process 256 elements per iteration, but each iteration becomes 4 times slower. Efficiently, it is 64 elements per operation. Since popcount is likely to be the slowest part of computation, we can say that it takes N/64 popcount_256 operations to compute the inner product.

EDIT: I decided to add an small example for the idea:

```
A = {01212012210};  //input array A
B = {21221100120};  //input array B
A1 = {01111011110};  //A should be stored in two halves like this
A2 = {00101001100};
B1 = {11111100110};  //B is stored in similar two halves
B2 = {10110000010};
A1 & B1 = {01111000110}, popcount = 6;  //computing pairwise and-s + popcounts
A1 & B2 = {00110000010}, popcount = 3;
A2 & B1 = {00101000100}, popcount = 3;
A2 & B2 = {00100000000}, popcount = 1;
res = 6 + 3 + 3 + 1 = 13   //summing all the popcounts
```

Comment: Instead of two separate bit-arrays, you could have packed 2-bit elements.  You can get A1 & B2 with a shift+and-mask.  This would take more instructions.  Also, a recent question was asking about 256b popcount, and the answer was that 4x `popcnt r64, r64` (SSE4.2) would probably be more efficient than the proposed code.

Comment: @PeterCordes Packing two arrays together is useless. It only make things more complex and perhaps more slow. Regarding popcount, I agree that the fastest version is perhaps calling popcnt for 64-bit integers 4 times. Maybe the solution I propose would be faster without any SSE/AVX registers at all (just use 64-bit integers). Anyway, the solution by Paul R with proper intrinsic seems to be faster.

Comment: Packing them is potentially more useful for whatever generates the inputs, and perhaps for whatever will look at the outputs.  And yeah, if you're going to use popcnt in a GP register, just use GP regs for everything.  `popcnt` can only run on port1, but Haswell can GP-reg `AND` / `ADD` on all four ALU ports.